# Does Non-atomic struct modification via _Atomic pointer produce data-race?

Tags: c, multithreading, concurrency, stdatomic, data-race

I'm trying to understand how C11 memory model works and wrote two functions containing expressions that `conflict` (in the sense of `5.1.2.4(p4)`):

```
struct my_struct{
    uint64_t first;
    int64_t second;
} * _Atomic instance;

void* set_first(void *ignored){
    uint64_t i = 0;
    while(1){
        struct my_struct *ms = atomic_load_explicit(&instance, memory_order_acquire);
        ms -> first = i++;
        atomic_store_explicit(&instance, ms, memory_order_release);
        sleep(1);
    }
}

void* print_first(void *ignored){
    while(1){
        struct my_struct *ms = atomic_load_explicit(&instance, memory_order_acquire);
        uint64_t current = ms -> first;
        char buf[100];
        memset(buf, '\0', sizeof(buf));
        sprintf(buf, "%" PRIu64 "\n", current);
        fputs_unlocked(buf, stdout);
        sleep(2);
    }
}
```

And the main function:

```
int main(void){
    struct my_struct tmp = {.first = 0, .second = 0};
    atomic_init(&instance, &tmp);
    printf("main\n");
    pthread_t set_thread;
    pthread_create(&set_thread, NULL, &set_first, NULL);

    pthread_t print_thread;
    pthread_create(&print_thread, NULL, &print_first, NULL);
    while(1){
        sleep(100);
    }
}
```

So I tried to prove if the program contains *no data-races*. Here are my thoughts:

1. We know that a release operation on an atomic object synchronizes with an acquire operation on the object. So `atomic_store_explicit(&instance, ms, memory_order_release);` in the `set_first` ***synchronizes with*** `atomic_load_explicit(&instance, memory_order_acquire)` in the `print_first`.
2. Since the side effect `ms -> first = i++` in the `set_first` function appeared before the `atomic_store_explicit(&instance, ms, memory_order_release);` in the program text I assumed it is ***sequenced-before*** it (This is I'm not sure about, could not find any normative references).
3. Combining bullets `1.` and `2.` implies that `ms -> first = i++` ***inter-thread happens before*** `atomic_load_explicit(&instance, memory_order_acquire);` so they are in the ***happens before*** relationships.
4. Applying the data-race definition we conclude that confliting actions `uint64_t current = ms -> first;` in the `print_first` function and `ms -> first = i++;` in the `set_first` function do not produce data-race.

So the behavior seems to be well-defined.

The doubtful thing is assumed that `ms -> first = i++;` ***sequenced before*** `atomic_store_explicit(&instance, ms, memory_order_release);` because they occurred one before another in the program text.

Is it correct or the program contains data races?

Comment: Why are you doing a `atomic_store_explicit(&instance, ms, memory_order_release);`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Modifying non-atomic objects through a non-`_Atomic` pointer is not *inherently* data-race UB.  (e.g. you could have an algorithm that did `int *p = shared_ptr++;` to have each thread grab its own slot in a non-atomic array.)

But in *this* case, you have a clear case of UB, because you have 2 threads accessing main's `tmp.first`, and they're not both reads.

---

A store with `mo_release` is sequenced after any previous stores (and loads), including non-atomic stores like `ms->first = ...`.  That's the point of release-stores vs. relaxed.

But the flaw in your reasoning is in step 1: `atomic_store_explicit(&instance, ms, memory_order_release)` in `set_first` **only *synchronizes-with* acquire loads that see the value stored!**  Acquire loads in other threads don't magically wait for a release store that hasn't happened yet.  The guarantee is that if/when you *do* load the value stored by a release store<sup>1</sup>, you also see all earlier things from that thread.

If the acquire load happens before the release store (in the global order, if there is one), then there's no synchronization with it.

**The acquire-load in both threads can happen simultaneously**, and then the fox is in the henhouse: `ms -> first = i++;` and `uint64_t current = ms -> first;` are running with no synchronization.

It's totally irrelevant that the writing thread will later do a release-store to store the same value back into `instance`.

---

Footnote 1:
   (The "release-sequence" language in the standard extends this to seeing the result of a RMW operation that modified the result of the initial release-store, and so on.)

---

As far as other threads are concerned, the `atomic_load_explicit` in `set_first` is basically irrelevant.  You might as well hoist it out of the loop.

Comment: I thought atomic types were permitted to have different size and representation from non-atomic. How can this ever not be UB?

Comment: @R..: The title is tricky.  It's an `_Atomic` pointer to a *separate* non-atomic object, with multiple threads dereferencing the same `_Atomic T*` to reach the same `T` object.  This is not asking about casting away the `_Atomic` qualifier; see [Assigning pointers to atomic type to pointers to non atomic type](//stackoverflow.com/q/55547081) for that.

Comment: You mean `T *_Atomic`. :-)

Comment: _only synchronizes-with acquire loads that see the value stored!_  Actually, I re-read the definition of the **synchronizes with** relation and there was the following condition I did not pay attention to (`5.1.2.4/p11`): _and reads a value written by any side effect in the release sequence headed by A._.

Comment: @SomeName: Yes, that's the critical part of the language in the standard that means acquire loads don't have to know about and wait for all possible future release stores. :P  (And thus are wait-free, for lockless atomic types.)

Comment: Since as defined in `5.1.2.4(p4)` the modification order is a _total order_ relation there would be no data race if `my_struct::first` was declared as `_Atomic uint64_t first;` (total order guarantees no ambiguity on which side-effect affecting the member is visible).

Comment: @SomeName: Yup, atomic pointer to atomic data would have no data-race UB.  Your program logic would still have a garden-variety race, with no guarantee of which value the reader would actually see (pre or post increment).  A total order would *exist*, but you'd have no guarantee of what that order is; that would be up to the vagaries of hardware and thread scheduling.  It would be possible for printing to sometimes skip one increment and sometimes skip 2, if the threads happened to get into very close lock-step.  (Unlikely because is prints before sleeping, so will usually sleep for longer.)

Comment: I don't really understand the problem with _pre or post increment_. Consider the case if  `_Atomic uint64_t first` and the value is stored as `atomic_store_explicit(&first, i++, memory_order_release);`. There is a sequence point after evaluation of `i++` and before the actual call to `atomic_store_explicit(&first, i++, memory_order_release);`. So it means `i++` is sequenced before the call to `atomic_store_explicit(&first, i++, memory_order_release)`.

Comment: @SomeName: Huh, what does that have to do with anything?  There was never any question about what the storing thread stores, just which store each load in the loading thread sees.  Whether it sees the stores from before (pre) storing `i++` or from after (post) storing `i++`.  It's not exactly an *increment* of `ms->first`, just a store of an increasing sequence, but same difference for the reader.